# DATABASE: Which one is better, list or extra table for connection?

Tags: mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

In my database I have a table for objects and I want to attach pictures (as links) to each of them, but I wonder which one is better:

1. Create extra column and store comma-seperated list or
2. Create extra table and connect object to its picture or
3. Is there any better way?

Comment: Read this: **[Is using multiple foreign keys separated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-separated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why)** Short answer: **It's very wrong.**

Comment: And this: **[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)** Short answer: **Yes, it's really that bad.**

Comment: I agree.  #2.  #1 is not a good idea.

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't like neither of them but in this case I think that's the best way. Thank you